# Boilerplate function name

Tags: c++, c++11

On projects I have been on, most have boilerplate code for creating a local variable for the function name.  What is the fastest/best way?  Or, is there a faster/better way to do it?  We are certain these functions will be called frequently, and it's a performance-critical project. So, what's the best way to initialize our function names?

Some I have seen:

```
/*1*/  const static std::string functionName("function1");
/*2*/  const static std::string functionName( __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ );
/*3*/  const std::string functionName("function1");
/*4*/  const char functionName [] = "function1";
```

Edit: I figured this would be obvious, but the reason we use such a declaration is so we can use the functionName variable to print out debugging information in the function. Maybe the reason it's not obvious is because we aren't implementing it well. I would love to hear about other ways to implement this.

Comment: The non-standard __FUNCTION__ is available in gcc and gcc-like compilers.

Comment: What is this function name going to be used for?  At first glance, I'd be inclined to say `static char const *const functionName = __func__;`, but if it is always used as a `string`, `static string const functionName{__func__};` might bet a better choice.

Comment: `__func__` is standard C++11

Comment: I have to ask _why_ this will be called at all, let alone frequently, let alone on "most" projects

Comment: Reason: to print out debugging information...

Comment: Use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` if you are dealing with overloaded or templated functions. `__func__` doesn't list the return type or arguments for `clang++` or `g++` (just the function name), and neither variable is supported in `msvc` anyways...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++11 8.4.1/8:

> The function-local predefined variable `__func__` is defined as if a definition of the form
>
> ```
> static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
> ```
>
> had been provided, where *function-name* is an implementation-defined string. It is unspecified whether such a variable has an address distinct from that of any other object in the program.
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
>   struct S {
>     S() : s(__func__) { } // OK
>     const char *s;
>   };
>
>   void f(const char * s = __func__); // error: __func__ is undeclared
> ```
>
> —end example ]

Comment: This is supported in every version of clang++ & g++ that supports `-std=c++11`, but is *not* supported in MSVC 10, 11 or 12. I haven't tested MSVC 13, but I wouldn't hold my breath.

Answer (score 2):

There is no time needed to initialize the function name pointer, because this will be done during compile/link time if you use only a pointer to the function name, which is a compile time constant.

```
void foo()
{
    static const char* myname =  __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ ;

}
```

Comment: Use `static char const *const` instead of just `static char const *` so that the entire type of the variable is `const` and the compiler can resolve it into read-only memory (or theoretically inline it out completely).